# django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ["'urvi' value must be an integer."]

Tags: python, django, exception, django-models

I am getting an error when I try to access the admin panel. It says ValidationError at /admin/["'urvi' value must be an integer."].

I have already tried using id and auto incrementing it but nothing works.

Models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.
Roles = (
    ('sales', 'SALES'),
    ('operations', 'OPERATIONS'),
    ('cashier', 'CASHIER'),
    ('frontdesk', 'FRONTDESK'),
    ('admin', 'ADMIN'),
    ('client', 'CLIENT'),

)


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,              default='none')
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=Roles,  default='client')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url
from NewApp import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$',views.register,name='register'),
```

Comment: Can you show the full traceback as well as the revant urls and views?

Answer (score 2):

`user` is a `OneToOneField` and the default you provide is a string! How can the ORM know how to translate that string to a `User` instance? You can either provide an `int` there which is questionable because you have make sure a `User` with that id is present in the database. Or - which is maybe what you want - make the field nullable (`null=True`) and set the default to `None` (not `'none'`).

Comment: It did not help.